# Velocity of separation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, relative-motion

Defining velocity of separation / approach , my textbook states that it is

> component of velocity of one body with respect to another along the line joining them .

Why is it that it is the component of velocity **along the line joining them ?
**

Is there a mathematical proof or an intuitive way to understand the phrase **along the line joining them ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all in the wording: *velocity of separation* is the velocity at which two objects may be approaching or separating from each other. So, if say objects $A$ and $B$ have velocities $\vec v_A$ and $\vec v_B$ say towards a third object $C$, then $\vec v_A$ and $\vec v_B$ themselves tell us nothing about the rate at which $A$ and $B$ approach each other - they tell us how they are approaching this third object they point to.

As such, if the objects have position vectors $\vec r_A$ and $\vec r_B$ respectively, if we want to know how fast they are approaching *each other*, then we are interested in the quantity,

$$\vec v_A \cdot \hat r_{AB} = \frac{\vec v_A \cdot (\vec r_B - \vec r_A)}{|\vec r_B - \vec r_A|}$$

which is the component of the velocity along the line that joins $A$ and $B$, and mathematically is known as the scalar projection.

---

To expand on the answer for the OP, recall that for a vector $\vec V$, we can find the $x$-component for example by taking the dot product with the unit vector $\hat x$, i.e.

$$\vec V = V_x \hat x + V_y \hat y, \quad \vec V \cdot \hat x = V_x.$$

We can see this since $\hat x = (1,0)^T$ and that $\hat x \cdot \hat x = 1$ and $\hat x \cdot \hat y = 0$. So, if we want instead the 'component' along the line between these two objects, we have to take the dot product with the unit vector in the direction along the line that joins them.

Comment: Nice explanation . But I am still confused about the mathematical derivation ?

Comment: Can you help with an intuitive explanation of separation ?

Comment: @AnmolAgarwal What is unclear about the idea of separation? Imagine two points travelling a plane. What would you say is their separation? It's the line between them...